# Convert Data URI to File

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a `data:image` encoded with base64 to a normal image file. So far my code looks like this:

```
this.toDataURL = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(layer0, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(layer1, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(layer2, 0, 0);
    var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    document.getElementById('canvascontent').value = url;
};
```

As you can see it creates an DataUrl that is afterwards displayed in an output(#cancascontent). The final output looks something like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo.................
```

My problem is that I need it necessarily decoded so that I can upload the images. My aim is that my javascript code displays the image in a new window like a "normal" image file. For example. like this:

```
http://example.com/images/pro_js_3e.png
```

How can I decode the base64 image?

Comment: You can upload the base64 data, and then have your server decode it and return you a URL.

Comment: Are there no javascript solutions?

Comment: @EmSta I dont udnerstand . you have a data/uri data and you want to save it in a file ?

Comment: @EmSta: You can convert it to a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), and upload that (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Comment: the string looks like this:  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo..     and yes i want to save or convert it to an normal png file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert the canvas to a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), and then upload that.

To convert to a Blob, try this script: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

Then you can use `canvas.toBlob` instead of `canvas.toDataURL`.

Then to upload it, you need to use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    var form = new FormData(),
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    form.append("image", blob, "filename.png");
    request.open("POST", "/upload", true);
    request.send(form);
}, "image/png");
```

This is un-tested, but should work.

Comment: Guess I should read the spec more often.  I didn't even realize that `form.append` could optionally take a filename as a 3rd param!

Comment: I just tested this in a few browsers, and it looks like Firefox and Safari simply ignore this third param.  IE10 and Chrome will ensure the name parameter of the Content-Disposition header associated with the file/blob's multipart boundary matches the value of this third param, but Safari and Firefox do not.  Bummer!

Comment: @RayNicholus: Yeah, I wasn't sure which browsers actually supported this or not.

Comment: It's a bit ironic that MDN documents this 3rd param, yet Firefox does not appear to support it.

Comment: @RayNicholus: According to the page Firefox 22 supports it.

Comment: Indeed it does.  I thought I was running 22, but I was running 21.  Eh, not good enough for me anyway.  Until all File API browsers have supportted this for a while, you'll have to include a parameter in the request with the actual filename when a Blob is being sent (or if you simply want to alter the filename client-side).  This includes cases where you slice the file into parts, since each part is also a Blob, and no longer a File.

Answer (score 5):

The code of https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob is a bit long.

My dataURLtoBlob() function code is much shorter.

Convert dataURL to blob, then use FormData and ajax to send.

```
function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
}

var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //canvas to png dataurl
//var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.8); //canvas to jpg dataurl
var blob = dataURLtoBlob(dataurl);

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("image", blob, "filename.png");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

Comment: Hi cuixiping I am having trouble grabbing the canvas data and pushing to a form..using your above code.. http://liquiddev.rtweb.com.au/image-submission trying to get canvas data and push it to my form image field but i keep getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` Can you see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: your dataurl argument is empty (undefined).

Answer (score 3):

So I don't think you can convert from base64 to a binary before you upload (there probably is a way, but it might be pretty convoluted). Your last requirement of serving it as a regular image link means that you have to store it on the server somewhere. This means that no matter what you do you're going to have to upload.

Given that, my opinion of the easiest solution would be to POST your base64 and have the server decode it, store it, and serve it.